# Google sheet: Best practice to get array data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Smith | 3 |
| Tom | 1 |

| Order_ID | Customer_ID | User_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3003 | 1 | =filter(Name,u_id = B2) |
| 3004 | 3 | =filter(Name,u_id = B3) |
| 3005 | 2 | =filter(Name,u_id = B4) |

I have the two tables above. The first one is a user list and the 2nd one order list. I have two named range in the first table: `Name` and `u_id`.

What I am trying to do is to get users' names from table1 and put them to the order table.
It is not very hard to use filter function for this. But it has a shortcoming: Since ew user data and order data is coming in every day, I have to manually drag the formula to fill the whole `User_Name` column even for the rows without data. This will generate #REF error, and I will have to refine my formula to

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",filter(Name,u_id = B2))
```

In my real project, I have to use a lot of `IF..ISBLANK()` to a point the formula is almost unreadable. Also, having to drag the formula from time to time ( Yes I know I can fill 1000 row at once ) doesn't feel very good.

So my question is, is there a better practice for this task? For example, some array function to put into Table2's C2 and I don't have to worry anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrayformula at the top of the column with iferror condition, and vlookup instead of filter

Try in C1

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(order_uid,{user_id,user_name},2,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This formula really helps. But if you put it in C1, how can C1 still display "names"? In my case it is empty, but if I put it in C2 there will be 1 row offset. To me the only solution is to make my named ranges start from row 2. Any better way?

Comment: C1 displays what is in the column user_name in regard of the term 'id'. Put 'User_Name' in A1 of the first table to display it. It's simplier as giving named ranges beginning in row 2.

Comment: Since my sheet is connected with other API, changing the heading will cause other problem.

Comment: A follow-up question, if in the user table, names are first name and last name, how can I do this? I tried `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ",true,iferror(VLOOKUP(order_user_id,{u_id,u_fn},2,0)),iferror(VLOOKUP(order_user_id,{u_id,u_ln},2,0))))` but it won't work.

Comment: OK I just found it. Ampersand is the answer. Thanks!